# HasLifecycleCallbacks dont work in symfony 6.2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, lifecycle

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MaintenanceBateauRepository::class)]
#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
class MaintenanceBateau
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $createdAt = null;

....
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }
```

He need any config for work?

If I add an object MaintenanceBateau , the data base  row is correct but the createdAt is Null!
It should be "Today"
Thanks for help

Comment: You're mixing attributes and annotations.

Comment: with attributes:
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }
I have same result...  Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **Attribute** starts with `#[` and an **Annotation** starts with `@`.
you cannot use both Attributes (e.g. `#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]`) and Annotations (e.g. `/** @ORM\PrePersist() */`) together, you must use one or the other and configure Doctrine to use the one you have selected. In your case, probably replace

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
```

with

```php
    #[Orm\PrePersist()]
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It run correctly now